# Probability of an event happening based on a second event multiple times

Tags: probability

If Event A has a 50% chance to happen, and Event B has a 5% chance to happen but only if Event A happens, what are the chances Event B happens 8 times in a row?

Comment: You give Readers little information about what is giving you difficulty.  Is the notion of conditional probability familiar?  Do you see how to apply it to the chance of event $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is given that $P(A)=0.5$, $P(A')=0.5$, and $P(B|A)=0.05$. From the law of total probability we can calculate, $P(B)$ as follows:

$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A')P(A') = 0.05*0.5 + 0*0.5 = 0.025$

The joint probability of independent events is simply the product of their probabilities. Therefore if $B$ is an independent event, then the probability that $B$ happens $8$ times in a row is $P(B)^8 = 0.025^8$.

Comment: Thank you, very clear and easy to understand.